# DUDAS para hacer CRUD de datos CON Jquery, Ajax y PHP + Modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, formularios, crud

Tengo un "historial" en una "tabla", de la siguiente forma:

```
$indices = '<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Selec</th>
                    <th>NumP</th>
                    <th>Fecha</td>
                    <th>Codigo</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Referencia</th>
                    <th>Detalles</th>
                    <th>Lente</th>
                    <th colspan="4">Opciones</th>
                </tr>';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$indices .= '<tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
                    <td>' .$row[npedido]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[fecha]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[cod_cliente]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[nombre_cliente]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[referencia]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[detalles]. '</td>
                    <td>' .$row[tipo]. '</td>
                    <td><i id="edit" class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-print"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
                </tr>';
}

$indices .= '</table>';
```

La tabla, la muestra de esta forma por PHP, desde ajax.

En PHP si que sabría hacerlo, sin embargo, no se me ocurre la forma de hacer esto con jQuery.

- He añadido 4 opciones, editar, ver, imprimir o eliminar, con 4 iconos cada una.

El problema, es que no se como hacer, para que al darle click al edit (por ejemplo) me muestre un "modal" para editar el pedido, obviamente con los datos del que he hecho click..

- En PHP, hasta ahora he utilizado el parámetro de la id, desde la URL, cosa que en jQuery y Ajax veo que no funcionaría así..

He probado.... esto:

```
<td><i id="'.$row[npedido].'" class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
```

** Ahora em gustaría saber como podría HABILITAR el MODAL al darle click a la imágen de la clase. fas fa.edit **

He estado probando así: pero no funciona

```
$( ".fa-edit" ).click(function() {
  $('#editarPedido').show();
});
```

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Puedes añadir un id al icono de editar, pero no por fuerza tiene que ser la misma para todos los iconos.  Podrias usar algo como `$row['cod_cliente']` como el id para saber cual registro tienes que editar.

Comment: Puedes hacer algo asi: `<td id="' .$row[cod_cliente]. '"><i id="edit" class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>` y cada icono dentro del td tendra un id diferente, o tambien puedes hacerlo dentro de la imagen

Comment: Yo tengo un método para esto, puesto que trabajo mucho con datatables y botones de edición y borrado. A cada botón le asigno su clase `.editar` `.borrar`, a la columna de id le pongo la clase  `.id` y luego al dar click en el botón me posiciono en la fila de ese botón con jQuery (encadenando `.parent()`) y finalmente busco el valor o texto de la columna `.id` para a partir de ahí jugar con la información, no es muy limpio ni recomendado pero es lo que me funciona

Comment: Me gustan ambas opciones, voy a probarlas para ver cuál me funciona mejor, a partir de aquí, como podría lanzar el modal ???

Comment: He decidido utilizar la opción de srJJ, aun que lo he añadido a la imagen, como podría ahora lanzar el modal ?